# Solve this matching with exponential running time in brute force manner

Tags: algorithm, matching, exponential

I have a question about matching. It is stated as follows.

I have a sequence which consists of two characters, {l,h}.

1. The character l can be mapped to a number from {1,2,3}. (l stands for low)
2. The character h can be mapped to a number from {4,5,6}. (h stands for high)

For example, I have a sequence (I call it the *original sequence*) with length = 6. It is [h,l,h,l,h,l].
This sequence can be transformed to a *detailed sequence* by the above mapping rules. A detailed sequence can be [6,1,5,2,4,3]. And for a sequence with length = 6, there are 6^3 detailed sequences.

I obtain a *difference sequence* from a detailed sequence by computing the pairwise differences. For example, my detailed sequence is [6,1,5,2,4,3], then the corresponding difference sequence is [6-1,1-5,5-2,2-4,4-3] = [5,-4,3,-2,1]. Hence, the largest value of an entry of the difference sequence is 5 resulted from 6 minus 1 and the smallest value of it is -5 resulted from 1 minus 6.

Now, I have a database consists of *m* difference sequences with length = 5.
My query sequence is a original sequence with length = 6. I want to find that:

Among the *m* difference sequences, what are those the corresponding original sequence can be my query sequence. If they do not exist, the program will return null set. If they exist, the program will return the set consists of them.

For example, for a difference sequence [5,-4,3,-2,1], its corresponding original sequence can be [h,l,h,l,h,l]. Hence, ff my query sequence is [h,l,h,l,h,l], [5,-4,3,-2,1] will be in the returned set if [5,-4,3,-2,1] is in the database.

For my real problem, the query sequence has length = n. And the database consists of *m* difference sequences with length = n-1.

The brute force method can be as follows:
For the input original sequence, enumerates its 3^n detailed sequences and gets the 3^n difference sequences. For each of the difference sequences, check that does it exist in the database.
The brute force will take O(3^n). I know that this exponential running time is not good.

I want to have a faster algorithm. An approximation algorithm also looks good to me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: So where is the effort in you trying to devise such an algorithm?

Comment: I am really sorry. I have indeed an idea but I have not written it in the question. My idea: I try to solve the problem starting from the differnce sequence instead of the original sequence. And hope to develop an alogrithm withing running time in turn of m instead of n. 

For each of the difference sequence, check whether it can be resulted from the input original sequence. 
I afraid this method will still be slow if the number of mapping attributes is large.

Comment: @YuColeman http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ---- http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @phil13131 Do you mean that I violate the suggestion. "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”"? If yes, I am really sorry about this. I ask because I want to have a more "concrete" idea. Thanks for your advice

Comment: @YuColeman I was referring to what Ed Heal also said. Since SO is a webpage where people help you in their own free time for free, you should do (and show!) that you have really done everything that you can, before asking for help. This is especially true for homework problems of students (I don't know if your problem is one, I just point it out, because it is a highly common issue on SO). But the help section here really helps!

Comment: @ phil13131 I see, thanks for your reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each difference sequence can be created from at most four h-l sequences.

So pre-process your database to build an index from h-l sequences to the difference sequences you're interested in.

For example:

```
[1, -1, 0, 2, -1]
```

This must come from one of these sequences:

```
[3 2 3 3 1 2] -> l l l l l l 
[4 3 4 4 2 3] -> h l h h l l
[5 4 5 5 3 4] -> h h h h l h
[6 5 6 6 4 5] -> h h h h h h
```

You can generate them all by starting the specific sequence from 1 to 6, and applying the differences. Sometimes the sequence will underflow or overflow the legal range of 1..6 and then you can discard that possibility.

Building this index is O(mn) time, and uses an additional O(mn) space. After you've built it, you can efficiently query a specific h-l sequence using the index.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your method of generating the detailed sequence from 1 to 6 by applying the differences in the difference sequence 
looks genius to me! I think there are typos for your example [1, -1, 0, 2, -1], the corresponding detailed sequence should be [2 1 2 2 0 1], [3 2 3 3 1 2], [4 3 4 4 2 3], [5 4 5 5 2 4], [6 5 6 6 4 5] (P.S I generate these by adding 1 to each entry and discard it when one of the entries underflow or overflow). However, I cannot see why "Each difference sequence can be created from at most four h-l sequences.".

Comment: [2 1 2 2 0 1] <--- is discarded due to underflow

Comment: @YuColeman yes, you're right -- I'd got the signs of the differences wrong, and had made an error in addition in my example. I fixed it now.

Comment: @YuColeman There's a relatively short proof that you can't generate more than 4 h-l sequences from a given difference sequence, but it's not critical. There's obviously not more than 6 h-l sequences (since the first number in a detailed sequence has to be 1-6 and the other numbers are given from this starting point and the differences). So if you can't see the upper bound of 4, you can just use the upper bound of 6 instead.

Comment: @YuColeman perhaps you can upvote my answer as well as accepting it?

Comment: May I know why the upper bound is 4? I know it is not critical. But I really want to know it. I understand that for two adjacent characters, h and h (hh in short), the difference can be {2,1,0,-1,-2}, ll can be {2,1,0,-1,-2}, hl can be {5,4,3,2,1} and lh can be {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}. I guess the upper bound 4 is related to this. But I cannot see the whole picture.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Since my reputation is low, the result cannot be displayed now.

Comment: Detailed sequences with the same difference sequence are translations up or down of each other. Let D be max - min of any of the detailed sequences. Then there's only 6 - D translations of this sequence that don't overflow, so if you want 5 different detailed sequences for the same difference sequence, then D has to be 1. But for D=1, there's only 3 different h-l sequences possible (llllll, hhhhhh, and a mix where the higher number maps to h and the lower to l). Thus you can't have 5 different h-l sequences. And 4 is possible as in the example in the answer.

Comment: "But for D=1, there's only 3 different h-l sequences possible", is it true?
For D=1, the h-l sequences can be llllll (both the max and min are from {1,2,3}), hhhhhh (both the max and min are from {4,5,6}), hlllll, lhllll,llhlll,lllhl (h maps to 4 and all the l map to 3), so 6 different h-l sequences.

Comment: What I wrote should be interpreted as "for a given difference sequence with D=1, there's only 3 different h-l sequences possible".